# Mounting Sharepoint shares using davfs2 yelds empty folder

Tags: linux, sharepoint

I'm trying to mount my employer's SharePoint document repository from Linux.
I followed the article published here: http://howto.unixdev.net/Linux-SharePoint.html

Everything seems perfect, I can authenticate and mount the shared folder, but the mount point is empty (well not exactly, I see a "lost+found" directory).

If I try the same path in explorer under Windows I see the files are there.
I have no errors in log files or at the CLI.

What can I try?

P.S. Since I see no replies, I am adding the content of /etc/fstab here, hoping that it can be useful to debug my problem:

```
http://AMENDED/bk/des/data\040administration/ /media/SharePoint davfs rw,noauto,user 0 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem: while looking at the way Internet Explorer formatted the URL I noticed a few letters were capitalized. So I tried capitalizing the same letters in /etc/fstab and voila, the repository was correctly mounted.

Here is my current /etc/fstab:

```
http://AMENDED/bk/des/Data\040Administration/ /media/SharePoint davfs rw,noauto,user 0 0
```

It is to be noted that introducing the all-lowercase url in windows explorer works correctly.

Comment: Where did you get that URL? I keep trying everything I can think of, and I only get "403 forbidden".

Comment: Well, I got it simply by accessing one of my shared resources through SharePoint. How could you ever get "403 forbidden" by accessing one of your resources? Are you by chance trying to type in IE the exact URL as you see above? That would not work: you have to access your own shared resources and see how IE formats the URL.

Comment: This is in /etc/fstab ... I get the 403 after mount. All this is from command line on Linux; I do not know how IE (the Windows browser?) would come into this. But thanx. Still searching for a functioning solution...

Comment: SharePoint is Windows software and, as usual with s/w from MS, it is meant to be used from Windows OS (and hence IE). That does not mean it cannot be used from other OSes/browsers, but you have to learn your way, and that often means experimenting with MS software to learn everything you can.
That said, if you get a 403 I think you have some problems with your account. You should try to access your resource from IE in Windows and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with non-ascii characters in filenames.
please look in.
http://savannah.nongnu.org/support/?108385

There are no solution/ Just use only ascii for filenames.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turns out to be with davfs2 code processing a response to PROPFIND in a case-sensitive manner. It's very easy to change it to case-insensitive processing before an official fix is made.

For more info see https://savannah.nongnu.org/support/index.php?108566

Comment: Could You please elaborate more about that `very easy to change`?